# writeback of dirty pages in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

I have a question regarding the writeback of the dirty pages. If a portion of page data is modified, will the writeback write the whole page to the disk, or only the partial page with modified data?

Answer (score 3):

The memory management hardware on x86 systems has a granularity of 4096 bytes. This means: It is not possible to find out which bytes of a 4096-byte page are really changed and which ones are unchanged.

Theoretically the disk driver system could check if bytes have been changed and not write the 512-byte blocks that have not been changed.

However this would mean that - if the blocks are no longer in disk cache memory - the page must be read from hard disk to check if it has changed before writing.

I do not think that Linux would do this in that way because reading the page from disk would cost too much time.

Comment: yes, to be emphasized is that this SINGLE bit of information to indicate whether the page is dirty or not, is in the PTE for EACH page.   So that single bit can only indicate whether that PAGE is dirty or not, but of course, this is hardware pagetable mechanism:   the pagesize can be changed as well (with other consequences).

Answer (score 1):

Upon EACH hardware interrupt, the CPU would like to write as much data as possible that the harddisk controller can handle - this size is defined by us as the blksize (or ONE sector, in Linux):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector

https://superuser.com/questions/121252/how-do-i-find-the-hardware-block-read-size-for-my-hard-drive

But waiting too long for SINGLE interrupt for a large file can make the system appear unresponsive, so it is logical to break the chunks into smaller size (like 512bytes) so that the CPU can handle other tasks while transferring each 512 bytes down.   Therefore, whether u changed one byte or 511 bytes, so long as it is within that single block, all data get written at the same time.   And throughout linux kernel, flagging the blocks as dirty for write or not, all goes by the single unique identifier:   sector number, so anything smaller than sector size is too difficult for efficient management.

All these said, don't forget that the harddisk controller itself also has a minimum block size for write operation.